# How to nested one component into another?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular8

Now in main component I do iteration of `items = [1,2,3]`:

```
<ng-content *ngFor="item in items">
   <app-form [item]="item"></app-form>
</ng-content>
```

As result I get this:

```
 <app-form [item]="item" type="1"></app-form>
 <app-form [item]="item" type="2"></app-form>
 <app-form [item]="item" type="3"></app-form>
```

How to better to rebuild DOM and make components nested?

For example insert `<app-form [item]="item" type="1"></app-form>` inside  `<app-form [item]="item" type="2"></app-form>`?

Should I do this in loop step or I can manipulate the ready DOM and rebuild it?

I need advice of professions, thank you!

Comment: Well have a look at "recursive components" a component that references itself. You could use the number of nested components as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Content Projection** will do what you are looking for. Anything that is nested inside the component's selector tags is able to be accessed using `<ng-content>`.

app-form.component.html

```html
<h1>App Form!</h1>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

app.component.html

```html
<app-form>
  <app-form></app-form>
</app-form>
```

This sample code will actually just render

```
App Form!
App Form!
```

Comment: Could you explain how did you get nested components?

Comment: component `  <app-form>` has own template inside. And how did you build `<app-form>
  <app-form></app-form>
</app-form>` manually? I need to do this dinamicly